# How to center align text in Extended Floating Action Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-ui, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I want to center align the text in the extended floating action button but I'm not able to do that. As you can see in the image below the text is not centrally aligned.

[image]

Here's is the code for extended floating action button:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/compress_start_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="S"
        app:backgroundTint="?android:colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please add these two lines in your ExtendedFloatingActionButton

```
 android:paddingStart="0dp"
 android:paddingEnd="0dp
```

Comment: Also needs `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 3):

use like this

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:text="@string/ic_lin_camera" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an ExtendedFloatingActionButton for text only, in your layout xml for the fab you can use

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
```

or extend the above style via

```
<style name="extended_fab_text_only" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/myTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

and you that as the style of your fab in your layout xml

```
style="@style/extended_fab_text_only"
```

Documentation: https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#extended-fabs
Under Extended FABs > Styles:

> Text-only when extended
> style Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton